# Careful pulling with Git: selective (manual) merge from origin/master to master

Tags: git, merge, diff, fetch, low-level

When using git, it seems to be a good idea to `fetch` and `merge` (as pointed out in this [blog](https://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/)) instead of just pulling in order to allow yourself to view the changes before merging.
This seems a reasonable and safe way to do things and I can follow so far.

However, what if I then do a `git diff` between master and origin/master and decide that most of the updates are good, but a couple of things need fixing? Is there a way to "manually" merge? I am looking for something similar to the editing that you get after a merge conflict which lets you decide on each single change - a little bit like `git add --patch`.

What I want is to have the power of editing things before merging origin/master into my own master, ideally with my favourite `difftool`.
I understand this could be done by applying the changes to `master` and then force pushing it with `git push -f`, but this seems a little brutal and unnecessary.

On the other hand, `cherrypick` sounds like a very promising name, but only allows to select commits, not actual changes on files.

How can one do a highly selective/manual merge? None of the merge strategies from the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) seems to allow enough manual control for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment you do the merge, use the parameter `--no-commit`.

```
git merge --no-commit <branch>
```

This will stop the merge at the time of creating the commit, leaving your status as a pending merge, which is exactly the same as when a conflict happens.

From this status, you can diff and make the necessary changes.

Comment: Added the hunk based reset as part of the accepted answer

Comment: I would even add `--no-ff` so `--no--commit` is not ignored in case it is a fast-forward merge.